# Separate customers by user in Stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to create a functionality using the Stripe API (not Stripe Connect) to let users add customers. If I understand this correctly, all customers will be added to my Stripe account. Is there a way I can distinguish which user added which customer, so that I can list all customers under one specific user?

I know Stripe Connect solves this problem, but it's not appropriate for my use case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

About the only way you'll be able to do this - beyond tracking it in your own application's database, which you should definitely do - is to add [Metadata to the Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata).

That said, you may want to [reach out to Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) and have them confirm that your use case makes sense; they may also have an alternative suggestion for you.

Answer (score 1):

As @floatingLomas said, you can use the metadata field to store user info when creating a new customer (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create), but as far as I know there's no specific API call to retrieve customers by metadata.
I mean, if your concern is to know who created a specific customer, it will be enough to retrieve that specific customer and look at its metadata field, but if you're looking for a solution which allow you to find all the customers added by a specific user, then I would suggest to create in your app a database table which keep track of that and do your searches through that.